# SSRS expression not displaying the right values

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

I'm trying to run the following expression:

```
=IIF((Fields!EntryFirstName.Value = " ") And (Fields!EntryLastName.Value = " " ), 
   "Team:" &  Fields!TeamName.Value,   Fields!EntryOrder.Value & " . "
     & Fields!EntryFirstName.Value & " " & Fields!EntryLastName.Value)
```

The table that the following is looking at is this one :
[image]

However running the above expression will only  return the following ( where EntryFirst name is the column EntryfirstName and so on):

Fields!EntryOrder.Value & " . "
         & Fields!EntryFirstName.Value & " " & Fields!EntryLastName.Value

for the whole report ( this one expression is part of a row group, if that would change anything)

[image]

Comment: are you sure formula should check for space `Fields!EntryLastName.Value = " "` and not an empty string `Fields!EntryLastName.Value = ""`? also your formula doesn't have a ending for when the condition was not met. 

    =IIF(
            (Fields!EntryFirstName.Value = "") And (Fields!EntryLastName.Value = "" ), 
               "Team:" &  Fields!TeamName.Value,   Fields!EntryOrder.Value & " . "
                 & Fields!EntryFirstName.Value & " " & Fields!EntryLastName.Value, some field )

Comment: @Kostya - I think you missed the comma after the Team for the ending condition. The empty string part is most likely the culprit (or they are multiple spaces) as you mention.

Comment: trim should fix that issue. `trim(Fields!EntryLastName.Value) =""`

Comment: Ah, it works, sql returned a string with so many spaces i couldn't evaluate it. Thanks :)

Comment: @Marc-AndreLeclair  If you are going to go to the trouble of trying to black out your data, you may want to make sure you don't have the transparency at any level other than *Not Transparent*...

Comment: @iamdave indeed, I did it really quickly. I'll keep it in mind next time. Thank you